# Whatman 41 filter uses for?

Tags: physical-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, elemental-analysis, filtering

I was reading a research article related to winter fog, so the researcher collected aerosols on Whatman 41 filters every 12h, and we know that **Whatman 41 filters** are usually used for **Qualitative analysis** than how come he find out the concentration of Aerosols through **Whatman 41 filter?** I am confused in the purpose of **Whatman 41 filter.** Why we use it and for what purposes it can be used and how can we use it?

Note: I need a basic explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Whatman number their filters according to the type of material e.g. glass fibre, paper, wet strengthened, hardened, ashless paper and also the porosity e.g. 6 micron,  2.5 - 5 micron. These are also related qualitatively to speed, e.g. fast, medium. So 54 is fast speed (because it's larger pore size) and hardened paper.
In this case, 41 is a fast (20 micron) ashless paper filter for coarse particles, but can also be used for pollution analysis as it can be purchased as sheets rather than circles for Buchner filter assemblies.
I'm no air pollution expert, but if the 41 paper was used in combustion analysis, one might get the particle measurements that way.

Comment: I add some speculation. Filtration means to collect a product. The latter is forced through at least by weight. Different is to evaluate pollution or similar issue. One can well create a scale or compare different cases without stopping all or most of the particulate. Porosity will play a role of course, but processes of adsorption, electrostatic interactions, or simply stopping some of the paths could work as well. Say, one let the filter a fixed amount of time and compare. But, I repeat, this is just reasoning. I am sure it is but not of its relation with protocols, common practice, etc.